# NHibernate Linq with multiple clauses gets unwanted data

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq, nhibernate

Using the latest stable NHibernate, I have the following query:

```
   private void Index(PromotionsRequest req)
    {
        PropertyBag["CurrentYear"] = DateTime.Today.Year;
        PropertyBag["CurrentManager"] = CurrentManager;
        IQueryable<Promotion> promotions;
        int totalPromotions;
        if (req.Commited)
            totalPromotions = NHibernateSession.Query<CommitedPromotion>().Where(p => p.IsHead == true).Count();
        else
            totalPromotions = NHibernateSession.Query<StagedPromotion>().Where(p => p.IsHead == true).Count();
        var totalPages = totalPromotions / maxpages;
        if (totalPages == 0)
            totalPages = 1;
        if (0 == totalPromotions % maxpages)
            totalPages++;
        var currentpage = req.Page;
        var numbers = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++)
            numbers.Add(i);
        var chunkednumbers = Chunk(numbers, maxpages);
        numbers = chunkednumbers.Single(p => p.Contains(currentpage)).ToList();
        if (req.Commited)
            promotions = NHibernateSession.Query<CommitedPromotion>().Where(p => p.IsHead == true).Cast<Promotion>();
        else
            promotions = NHibernateSession.Query<StagedPromotion>().Where(p => p.IsHead == true).Cast<Promotion>();
        //
        if (req.Status == Status.Active)
        {
            promotions = promotions.Where(p => p.From < DateTime.Now && p.To > DateTime.Now);
        }
        else
            if (req.Status == Status.Expired)
            {
                promotions = promotions.Where(p => p.To < DateTime.Now);
            }
            else
                if (req.Status == Status.Unstarted)
                {
                    promotions = promotions.Where(p => p.From > DateTime.Now);
                }
        //
        if (req.Commited)
        {
            if (req.Sort == Sort.Newest)
            {
                promotions = promotions.OrderBy(p => p.Created);
            }
            else
                if (req.Sort == Sort.Newest)
                {
                    promotions = promotions.OrderByDescending(p => p.Created);
                }
                else
                    if (req.Sort == Sort.Modified)
                    {
                        promotions = promotions.OrderBy(p => p.Modified);
                    }
        }
        //
        promotions = promotions
              .Skip(itemsperpage * (currentpage - 1))
              .Take(itemsperpage);
        var promotionsCreated = NHibernateSession.Query<Manager>().Select(p => p.PromotionsCreated).Sum();

        PropertyBag["PromotionsResponse"] = this.listbinder.GetListOfPromotionsFrom(promotions, currentpage, totalPages, totalPromotions, promotionsCreated, req.Sort, req.Status, numbers);
    }
```

This query, depending on whether req.Commited is true or not, either gets instances of CommitedPromotion type or StagedPromotion type. The base class, Promotion, has a property, IsHead, which I use to filter them. In this case, I only want the promotions which have the IsHead == true. The problem? This query returns even those with IsHead == false. From my knowledge, that shouldn't happen. This happens at the point where I start to filter by the Status and Sort enums:

```
  if (req.Sort == Sort.Newest)
                {
                    promotions = promotions.OrderBy(p => p.Created);
                }
```

If I debug here, I see that it gets promotions with IsHead == false.

Answer (score 0):

`IsHead == true` is only filtered for not committed Promotions hence commited Promotions can have `IsHead = false`

other problems i see

- the second `if (req.Sort == Sort.Newest)` should be Sort.Oldes

Comment: It's a typo, in the original post I should have written IsHead instead IsMaster.

Comment: have you checked the generated sql if the condition is applied?